# Devices disconnecting during application installation through Android studio using new MACBOOK

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, adb

Have recently received a new Macbook upgrade at work and had to go through the whole installation process of all the IDE's etc that I use. Have not had this issue in the past, but since the install of Android studio, every time I try to run the project on to a physical device, the device disconnects during the installation process via ADB.

'Installation failed because the device "device name" disconnected'.

I am using the ADB supplied by the SDK tool, which is set in my home path.

USB debugging is set and file transfer is selected.

Before the test is run, I check the device list with 'adb devices' to ensure that it is in the list, which it is but after the error message, it is removed from this list.

My colleague who also upgraded, does not currently have this issue, so am assuming that there is not an issue due to the power required from the USB port, as the mac's are the same spec.

With this machine and the adapter that came with it, only usb 3.0 ports are available, but as I said, colleague has the same spec and no current issues.

- Turning off the Instant run
- Built, Cleaned, Rebuild
- Re-synced
- Cleaned project with gradle wrapper of the project
- Invalidated caches and restarted
- My project does contain special characters + colleague's is fine
- Tried multiple cables I know work
- Memory on the devices is not an issue
- Tried multiple devices that work for my colleague
- Using the correct build variant, one that also work for colleague
- Restarted ADB

'Installation failed because the device "device name" disconnected'.

Comment: USB debugging is set and file transfer is selected: is not required. Try to run adb command from home folder in a terminal

Comment: I have the same problem with two tablets. Were you able to solve it yet?

Comment: I actually did. But I did it by a complete fresh install of the macbook.. Wiped everything which in turn made me install Android tools again. I assume it was something to do with how I installed it.

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57589248/installation-failed-due-to-null-android-studio-3-5/58095554#58095554